# Weird behavior of default copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, object, constructor, copy, implicit

I've encountered a weird behavior during learning about implicit copy constructors in C++. This is about this bunch of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
public:
    char* name;
    int age;

    Person( const char* the_name, int the_age )
    {
        name = new char[strlen( the_name ) + 1];
        strcpy( name, the_name );
        age = the_age;
    }

    ~Person()
    {
        delete[] name;
    }
};

int main(){
    Person p1( "Tom", 22 );

    Person p2( p1 );
    p2.name = "Bill";

    // the output is: "Tom"
    std::cout << p1.name << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

By default, copying an object means copying its members, therefore while creating `p2` object using default copy constructor it should copy merely a pointer `name`, not the character array it points to. Therefore changing `name` member of object `p2` should change the `name` member of object `p1`. Thereupon `p1.name` should be `"Bill"` not `"Tom"`.

What's wrong in my reasoning? Why it's printing `"Tom"`?

Comment: It is printing `Tom` because that's what `p1.name` points to. Making  `p2.name` point elsewhere doesn't change that. Do read about the [rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) though. It will prevent lots of bugs of this kind.

Comment: Quote from the standard:
"The implicitly-defined copy constructor for a non-union class X performs a memberwise copy of its subobjects. [n3126.pdf section 12.8 §16]"

So copying the pointer(name) it's merely copying the pointer, not the character array it points to. I've read several documents and there are that kind of explanations, but it's inconsistent with real output of program.

Comment: Yes, the subobject is the pointer `name`, not whatever `name` is pointing at... If I place a sign on my property that directs at a lake nearby, it doesn't mean I own the lake. At most I own the sign.

Comment: Yes, `p2.name` was copied from `p1.name` so both pointed to `Tom`. Then you changed `p2.name`. I don't understand how the example contradicts the quote. Where exactly did an expected memberwise copy not happen?

Comment: Member copy happened, but it should copy merely pointer. So `p1.name` and `p2.name` points to the same memory, but their pointers are in different memory. Therefore changing memory pointed by `p1.name` should also change what `p2.name` points.

Comment: You don't change the memory pointed at by `p1.name`. Did your C++ book not cover why C-strings are copied with `strcpy`?

Comment: You seem to be confusing pointers with references. `p2.name` is not a reference to `p1.name`, it's just a pointer that initially points to the same address as `p1.name`. Reassigning one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: So how is it possible that `p1.name` and `p2.name` point to the same address and changing the memory from this address is merely visible from `p1.name` but not from `p2.name`. I'm totally confused :(

Comment: It's the same situation as `const char* p1 = "Tom"; const char* p2 = p1; p2 = "Bill";`.

Comment: Get a piece of paper. Write "Tom" and "Bill" in two corners. In other corners draw circles with p1.name and p2.name. Near those circles draw small arrows pointing to "Tom". Those are your pointers, and arrows are their values. Now erase arrow in p2 circle and draw new one, pointing to "Bill". You reassigned p2 pointer. Now, what is written in corner, p1 arrow is pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, copying an object means copying its members

Yes.

> therefore while creating `p2` object using default copy constructor it should copy merely a pointer `name`, not the character array it points to.

Correct.

> Therefore changing name member of object `p2` should change the name member of object `p1`.

Nope. Yes, `p2.name` and `p1.name` point to the same memory location, but that doesn't mean that changing the pointer *value* of `p1.name` will change the value of `p2.name`. If that were `int`s, would you be surprised if changing `p1.name` has no effect `p2.name`? Because it's the same thing here. You have two different variables, and changing one's value doesn't change the value of the other.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;

int* ptrA = &a;
int *ptrA2 = &a;

*ptrA = 1; // now a == 1
*ptrA2 = 4; // now a == 4

ptrA2 = &b;

*ptrA2 = 10; // now b == 10
*ptrA = 3; // now a == 3, a != 10
```

Comment: I thought that in my case there is just one variable (chars in memory) and two pointers point to it.

Comment: @jaayy Not really. You have just two variable, the two pointers, pointing to some memory location. But they are different variables, so changing one doesn't change the other, except of course if you are accessing the memory pointed by the two pointers, as they point to the same place.

Comment: I don't understand. I have two variables which are in the same memory location? You said I have two variables, the two pointers, pointing the same memory location. So first pointer points to first variable and second pointer points to second variable and simultaneously pointers point to same memory location? It's inconsistent for me.

Comment: @jaayy No I don't mean that. The two pointers have different memory locations of course, but they point to the same location. The first points to the memory location, and the second one too, to the same one.

Comment: So if memory which is pointed by first will be changed, memory which is pointed by second should be changed as well, because it's the same memory. Am I right?

Comment: I already know what was my problem. I thought that writing line like this `p2.name = "Bill";` I'm changing memory what is pointed by `p2.name`, but I'm allocating new memory for string `"Bill"`. If I would do `p2.name[1] = 'b'` the output of program would be `'Tbm'`. Thanks for help.